# While executing vbscript, kill the vbscript on keyboad button event

Tags: vbscript

I want to generate an event on keyboard button press. On that event, the running vbscript should be closed. I don't want to add any other scripting lanuguage. If anyone has an idea how to do this, please help me.

Here is my code so far:

```
 Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 If(objShell.SendKeys ("{Esc}") == "1")Then
   WScript.echo "del pressedd"
 End If
```

Comment: fixed grammar, removed some unnecessary phrases including exclamation points.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in plain VBScript.  The best you could do is to periodically query the user.  Eg:

```
Do
    ' lots of code here...
Loop While MsgBox("Keep going?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK
```